# How to authenticate user with Django AllAuth using either email or username in one field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Is there any way in Django AllAuth with configuration `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'` to send text from input `"USERNAME OR EMAIL"` and authenticate it automatically? I don't mean frontend logic, just AllAuth authentication. So it would get a JSON with fields for instance `"username_email" : "myusername", "password" : "password"` or `"username_email" : "myemail@gmail.com", "password" : "password"` and it would automatically check whether a user with nick or email `myusername` exists and his password is `password`. In the second case it would also check whether a user with nick or email `myemail@gmail.com` exists and his password is `password`. If so the user would be authenticated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need a custom authentication backend [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend)

Something like this:

```
class MyAuthenticationBackend:

    def authenticate(self, email_username=None, password=None):
        if "@" in email_username:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email_username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        else:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=email_username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        if getattr(user, 'is_active', False) and user.check_password(password):
            return user
        return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then in your form view:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class LoginView(FormView):
    template_name = 'my-auth/login.html'
    form_class = LoginForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user = authenticate(email_username=data['email_username'], password=data['password'])
        if user is None:
            form.add_error(None, _('Wrong email/username'))
            return self.form_invalid(form)
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('somewhere')
```